# Calculate $\lim _{x \to \infty} (\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt)^{2}(\int_0^x e^{2 t^2} dt)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Please find a mistake in my solution.

$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt\right)^{2}} {\int_0^x e^{2 t^2} dt} = \text{|by d'Hospitals|} = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2 e^{x^2} \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt }{e^{2 x^2}} = 2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x^2}}{2x e^{x^2}} = 0.$$

Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha says that the solution is $\infty$.

Comment: Is $\int \limits_0^x e^{t^2} dt$ the same in both numerator and denominator?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [Compute $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{[\int^x_0 e^{y^{2}} dy]^2}{\int^x_0 e^{2y^{2}}dy}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1231158). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(%5Cint_0%5Ex%20e%5E%7Bt%5E2%7D%20dt)%5E%7B2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Check your Wolfram Alpha code.